# JQuery.ajax(), cache option IE8

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser-cache

Hello everyone I was trying to understand this sentence (from [JQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) about cache option:

> except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been
>   requested by a GET.

If anyone can help me with some simple example and explanation I will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: If you make a GET request in IE8 and then later make a POST request to the same URL, IE8 will incorrectly return the cached response rather than doing the POST.

Comment: If i understand for example i am doing some GET request for google.com for example, Than doing POST the POST won't even happen, I will get the cached GET, So by doing cache = false, There will be no cache at all and if there is no cache i will be able to send the POST can you tell me if i am right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [@Kevin B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b)'s comment "If you make a GET request in IE8 and then later make a POST request to the same URL, IE8 will incorrectly return the cached response rather than doing the POST."

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test1.htm"
});

/* In IE8 this comes from the cache */
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "test1.htm"
});

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test2.htm",
  cache: false // adds a timestamp to the querystring
});

/* Even IE8 avoids the cache */
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "test2.htm"
});
```

Comment: Thank you richaux, So just if you can confirm i got it right: After first ajax request with GET and cache = true test1.htm was cached, Than after another ajax request with POST to the same url(test1.htm) the browser return to the ajax POST request the test1.htm that was cached before?

Comment: Thank you so much richaux and Kevin.